# button event gets fired after page_load but can't use PreLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, web

I am developing a Web application using C# with asp.net. I have a sub-view in a Multiview control, which can be 3 states.

---

I change an enumeration in code to determine the state of the page. This is done by clicking one of the three buttons.

---

But my problem is, 
   the button event will be fired after the `page_load` event, which loads the data of the page based on the enumeration, so the cycle goes as follows:

> Click Button -> Load Page -> change enumeration.

So the changes won't be displayed. Only when i click the button a second time it shows the new data, because then the enumeration is changed and it loads. But I can't load the data in another event like Page_PreLoad because I'm dynamically creating controls with events, which won't work then. Thanks for helping!

Comment: It is not very clear what the problem could be without any code, but did you wrap everything (except the creating of the dynamic controls) in Page_load in a IsPostBack check? `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { }`

Comment: @VDWWD the problem is, I can't load anything in Page_Load because the event is triggered before the Button Events get triggered.